# How to convert ArrayList[] Transaction into a Transaction[] Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I need to create a dynamic `Listview` filled with transactions already in "`Transaction`" objects, but because the number of transactions can be variable, first I need to create an `ArrayList` of `Transaction` objects and convert it to an array to pass it to the Listview Adapter. I was trying to do so in this way:

```
ArrayList <Transaction> transaction_data2 = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
            transaction_data2.add(new Transaction("0000324455678", "25/05/2014","2.750,25"));
            transaction_data2.add(new Transaction("0000324456599", "25/05/2014","12.000,00"));
            transaction_data2.add(new Transaction("0000324456621", "26/05/2014","780,00"));
            transaction_data2.add(new Transaction("0000324456686", "27/05/2014","658,50"));
            transaction_data2.add(new Transaction("0000324456686", "27/05/2014","658,50"));
            transaction_data2.add(new Transaction("0000324456699", "27/05/2014","128,00"));

            Transaction transaction_data[] =  new Transaction[transaction_data2.size()]; 
            transaction_data = (Transaction[]) transaction_data2.toArray();
```

But I got this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to
>   com.myproyect.Transaction[]

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
        Transaction transaction_data[] =  new Transaction[transaction_data2.size()]; 
        transaction_data = (Transaction[]) transaction_data2.toArray(transaction_data);
```

`toArray` with no arguments returns an Object[] whereas when you pass an array it will fill that array with items.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was a "late night" parameter missed.

Answer (score 4):

```
Transaction[] transaction_data = transaction_data2.toArray(new Transaction[transaction_data2.size()]);
```

Please research first: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like This.

```
ArrayList<Transaction > stock_list = new ArrayList<Transaction >();
stock_list.add("stock1");
stock_list.add("stock2");
Transaction [] stockArr = new Transaction [stock_list.size()];
 stockArr = stock_list.toArray(stockArr);
for(String s : stockArr)
    System.out.println(s);
```